# Access main window setTimeoutID in same domain iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dom-events, settimeout

I am trying to alert user for inactivity about 30 secs. So in my application I am setting timeout for alert.

Main window code:

```
<script>
    var timeoutID = setTimeout('alert("You are logged out due to inactivity.")', 30000);
</script>
```

iFrame :

```
<script>
  $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
     clearTimeout(timeoutID);
     var timeoutID = setTimeout('alert("You are logged out due to inactivity.")', 30000);
  });
</script>
```

Now, when I am in iFrame and doing something my main window alert still comes. Not sure how to reset the same timeoutID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`top.timeoutID`

Use it also when setting the new timeout, otherwise you will not be able to access to the timeout when navigating away from the iframe.

there is also a typo: `fucntion`